# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar una cadena de texto desde CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, replace

necesito remplazar una cadena de texto y no se como hacerlo desde el CMD.

Comment: remplazar la cadena en donde? en la misma consola? en un archivo? en una locacion remota?

Comment: Si se trata de una variable, estos links te pueden ser útiles. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Answer (score 1):

Fácil:

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE file.txt | SUBSTITUTE file.txt
```

Comment: Hola Javier, aunque esta respuesta puede servir de guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace el código que compartes? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: ¿Abriste la consola para ver si existe el comando `SUBSTITUTE`? Porque a mi no me lo reconoce.